# Проблема с передачей значения объекта оператором присваивания

Tags: c++

Есть следующий код:

```
//Конструктор
CellSheet::CellSheet(int s)
{
size = s;
//Тут происходит объявление двумерного массива
Cell **sheet = new Cell*[size]; // строк в массиве
for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
    sheet[i] = new Cell[size];

//А тут должна быть инициализация
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<size;j++)
        {
            sheet[i][j] = new Cell(); //Ошибка 
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка следующая:

> no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Cell' and 'Cell')

В Java я привык, что оператор присваивания просто работает. В примерах, которые я нашёл в сети объекты тоже создавались подобным образом. Ошибка, наверняка, кроется в работе с указателями, которые я ещё до конца постиг.
Что же я делаю не так?

Comment: Только что обнаружил, что в C++ оператор присваивания можно переопределять. Вопрос следующий: ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО ли это делать при работе с объектами?

Comment: В Java у вас присваиваются не объекты, а _ссылки_ на объекты. В C++ присваиваются именно объекты.

Comment: Сгенерированный по умолчанию оператор присваивания копирует значения полей. Это может быть то, что надо, а может и не быть (представьте себе, что одно из полей — указатель, и подумайте о последствиях). Если стандартный оператор присваивания не подходит, его нужно переопределить.

Comment: Да знаю я, что в Java ссылки передаются. Я на передачу по значению и надеялся. В любом случае, спасибо. Буду пробовать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new Cell()` возвращает `Cell*`, тогда как `sheet[i][j]` ожидает `Cell`, отсюда и ошибка.  Вы можете переписать Ваш код так:

```
for(int j = 0;j<size;j++)
{
    sheet[i][j] = Cell(); 
}
```

и ошибка должна уйти, но в этом просто нет смысла, т.к. тоже самое уже произошло в другой строчке:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
    sheet[i] = new Cell[size];
```

Здесь, Вы создаёте `size` строк(row) размером `size` каждая. При этом, у каждой `Cell` из этой строки вызывается конструктор по умолчанию. Т.е. всё `Cell` инициализированы после этого цикла, никакой дополнительной инициализации не требуется.

Comment: Спасибо! теперь всё встало на свои места.